# Get a reference to the edit button in a gridview with FindControl

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My question is: What is the ID of an Edit button defined as a CommandField in a GridView? I want to be able to reference this button using the FindControl method in the code-behind, but, since I don't know the Edit button's ID, I can't. I have to reference it by index.

This is the detail of what I'm trying to do:

I have an ASP.NET 4.5.1 GridView control with an edit button and a delete button. They are defined as follows:

```html
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" UpdateText="Save" ShowDeleteButton="false" ValidationGroup="vgParcelComments" />
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteParcelComment" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure that you want to delete this comment?');" CommandName="Delete" CssClass="removeParcelComment">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In the RowDataBound event for this GridView in my code-behind page, I can manipulate the Delete button with the following line of code:

`e.Row.FindControl("btnDeleteParcelComment").Visible = False 'The delete button`

This hides the Delete button. But, for the Edit button, I can't determine what its ID is, so I can't use the FindControl function to access it. The best that I can do is reference it by index, like so:

`e.Row.Cells(4).Visible = False 'The edit button`

I tried to look at the Edit button's ID using the following statement:

`Dim itsId As String = e.Row.Cells(4).ID`

but Nothing was always returned when this line executed.

Tak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look in the Controls collection of the cell for the LinkButton which has `Edit` as its `CommandName`:

```vb
Dim editButton As LinkButton = Nothing
For Each cell As DataControlFieldCell In e.Row.Cells
    For Each ctl As Control In cell.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is LinkButton Then
            Dim commandButton As LinkButton = CType(ctl, LinkButton)
            If commandButton.CommandName = "Edit" Then
                editButton = commandButton
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Tak, @ConnorsFan. I had a few problems with your code above. First, the type of the object returned in the ctl variable was a DataControlLinkButton. I couldn't convert this type to a Button. So I couldn't examine the CommandName property. However, based on the inspiration of this code example, I fooled around with it for awhile, and finally came up with this, which I will use:

Comment: `Dim editButton As LinkButton = Nothing;
For i As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Controls.Count - 1;
  Dim cell As DataControlFieldCell = e.Row.Cells(i);
  If TypeOf cell.ContainingField Is CommandField Then;
    For Each item In cell.Controls;
      If TypeOf item Is LinkButton Then;
        editButton = CType(item, LinkButton);
        If editButton.Text = "Edit" Then;
          Exit For;
        End If;
      End If;
    Next;
    Exit For;
  End If;
Next;
If editButton IsNot Nothing Then;
    editButton.Visible = False 'The edit button;
End If;`